# Error in Mysql Query #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysql-error-1064

Executing the query below throws this error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1`:

```
INSERT INTO farmpreparation (idno, loanno, plotno, initialcost, primarycost,` `secondarycost, tertiarycost, manuallabour, machinelabour, othercost,` `totalcost, typeofcost, addedby, timestamp) VALUES ('234354554',` `'34206bfce6ac247af85d77b840e9d8cf', 'SDDF454677', '2000', '0', '2000', '2000',` `'2000', '0', '0', '8000', 'ESTIMATE', 'admin', '2015-11-03 01:50:49'
```

Comment: missing a closing `)` from the values

Comment: can you post the full error where its asking you to use correct syntax near in the line...

Comment: that's the full error where i have quoted

Comment: Is the missing ) at the end the "real" error or just some copy&paste artifact?

Comment: did you tried using the ')' at the end like others are pointing..

Comment: thanks guys the ')' was missing now its working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this you have ')' missing

```
INSERT INTO farmpreparation (idno, loanno, plotno, initialcost, primarycost, secondarycost, tertiarycost, manuallabour, machinelabour, othercost, totalcost, typeofcost, addedby, timestamp) VALUES ('234354554', '34206bfce6ac247af85d77b840e9d8cf', 'SDDF454677', '2000', '0', '2000', '2000', '2000', '0', '0', '8000', 'ESTIMATE', 'admin', '2015-11-03 01:50:49')
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure about your datatypes and please add ) at end of your statement.